# How does one mix 'Reference' and 'No Reference' belongTo relationships in one Domain Class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, belongs-to, grails-domain-class

In **Grails**  [**`belongsTo`**](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html) allows one **domain class** to establish a *cascading* relationship with another domain class.  There are two styles of relationships when using `belongsTo`: **Reference** and **No Reference**.  Reference creates a property on the owned object while No Reference merely establishes an invisible GORM relationship.

**Example parent domain-class:**

```
class Car {
    Engine engine
}
```

**`belongsTo` without Reference property:**

```
class Engine {  
    static belongsTo = Car  
}
```

**`belongsTo` with Reference property:**

```
class Engine {  
    static belongsTo = [car:Car]
}
```

Not to hard right, however the trouble for me starts when we start using multiple belongsTo references:

**`belongsTo` with multiple back references**:

```
class Engine {
     static belongsTo = [car:Car, user:User]
}
```

**multiple `belongsTo` relationships without property references**:

```
class Engine {
     static belongsTo = [Car, User]
}
```

Here's the problem, **how do I mix the two above styles?**

Say I want a property reference for the `User` but not for the `Car`, how would I write that `belongsTo` call?

Any information on how to mix No Reference relationship links with Reference property in a single domain class would help.

Links:

- [Using Grails Object Relational Mapping (GORM)](http://efforts.embedded.ufcg.edu.br/web/?p=7)
- [belongsTo - grails.org](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html)
- [This question reposted by me on the official Grails forum](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-does-one-mix-Reference-and-No-Reference-belongTo-relationships-in-one-Domain-Class-tp3503856p3503856.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Engine {
     User user
     static belongsTo = [Car, User]
}
```

That said, I always use the map (reference) syntax over the list (no reference) syntax because I like mine to be bi-directional.